# Reading files into fortran

Tags: format, fortran

So I'm writing some code in Fortran that multiplies a square matrix by itself. But the matrix I have to multiply is in a file and I'm having some issues reading it into the program. I think its because the sample data is in the following format:

3

101

010

101

The first row is the dimension of the matrix, and each row is a now in the matrix, but there aren't spaces in between the entries. So I guess my question is how do I split up those rows as I read them into a 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the first number as `N` and use it to allocate an array of dimension N by N.  Then read a row at a time of this array: `array (i, 1:N))` for i=1 to N.   See [Fortran: reading a row of numbers into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989125/fortran-reading-a-row-of-numbers-into-an-array) for the format to use.

Answer (score 0):

Read using format

```
read (1,*) n
allocate(A(n,n))
do i=1,n
  read (1,'(1000i1)'),A(i,:)
enddo
```

it does not matter whether you declare extra "i1" than actually needed